# Saving and displaying formatted text with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On my website, I want user comments to have some options in regards to formatting.

For example, I would want `*Sample Text*` to become bold, `**Sample Text**` to become italic, etc.

But I also want users to be able to escape formatting.

So `\*italic text\*` and `\*\*bold text\*\*` would escaped.

Ideally I'd like have this saved as something like `<i>Sample text</i>` and `<b>Bold text</b>` in the database.

Also I'd want, for example, to have links saved like so: `[this is a link to google](www.google.com)`

Should this be done on the front end, or formatted in the back end and displayed by escaping the comment like so : `{!! $comment !!}`

Comment: check this plugin it may help you https://simplemde.com/

Comment: @Joseph I don't really need help with the wysiwyg, I can make one on my own. This is more about saving and displaying.

Comment: The basic idea is that you need a parser – whether you choose to write your own, or leverage an existing package. You can decide if it makes sense to do the parsing on the frontend or the backend. If you do it on the backend, I think it makes sense to parse it before saving it to the db. If your parser is on the frontend, you'd probably want to save the un-parsed text to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a look towards markdown
https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown

and 2 columns in DB. with raw text (markdown) and generated html text (will be displayed in layout)